# Table navigator moves out of view when the table longer than a screen size

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a table view that has a navigation bar at the top. The problem is that when the table becomes full the navigation disappears when I scroll through the table. Is there any way of fixing it so that it does not move with the table?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have added the NavigationBar to your UITableViews Header View...

The easiest way to solve your problem is, go to XCode Designer, where you have added the UITableView, and the UINavigationBar....

Cut or delete the NavigationBar

Move the TableView with drag and drop a little bit lower

Insert, or add a NavigationBar directly to the View, not in the TableView, then move the TableView higher, untill it fits under your NavBar. Also resize your TableView, to fit the Screen now...

After this the NavBar wont move while scrolling your TableView

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried this but there appears no way of moving the TableView.