# UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have set up a `UIViewController` with a table view and cell added. The delegate and data source are linked to the table view. However I getting this error and I am confused as to why. The code works when I use it with a `UITableViewController` but not with a `UIViewcontroller`. The reason for wanting to use a `UIViewController` is that the navigation bar scrolls with the table when using a `UITableViewController` and I was advised on here to use a `UIViewController` and add the Table view.

```
#import "ObViewControllerObservationsTable.h"
#import "ObAppDelegate.h"
#import "Observations.h"
#import "ObViewControllerTableDetail.h"
#import "ObViewControllerMainMenu.h"

@interface ObViewControllerObservationsTable ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *teacherNames;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *detailsButton;
@end

@implementation ObViewControllerObservationsTable

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Observations"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"obsTeacherName" ascending:YES]];
NSError *error = nil;
self.teacherNames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
return [(ObAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.teacherNames.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"teacherCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
Observations *currentList = [self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = currentList.obsID;
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Observations"];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"obsTeacherName" ascending:YES]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.teacherNames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (self.teacherNames.count == 0)
    {
        self.detailsButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.detailsButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
}
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
obsID = [[self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] obsID];
self.detailsButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why the navigation bar scrolls?  Seems strange to me and I would suggesting fixing that 'problem' rather than trying to make a UIViewController act like a UITableViewController.

Comment: I have tried but the advice from here was to redo it this way. Appreciate the help.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15419486/1286639 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns `nil` if no reusable object exists in the reusable-cell queue. (See [UITableView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Here is how it should be:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"teacherCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        // More initializations if needed.
    }
    Observations *currentList = [self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = currentList.obsID;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried the above and now get this error: -[UITableView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Any ideas?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths, the selector `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is usually sent to an object which implements `UITableViewDatasource` protocol. Please check, which object is referenced in `tableView.datasource` property? It seems to me you have `tableView.datasource = tableView;`. Or please check bindings in Interface Builder. `tableView.datasource` should point to your view controller where you implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Sorry, can't say some specific without seeing code or project.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in replying - I have very rare internet access. The datasource and the delegate are currently linked to the table view. I am not sure how to link this to the View Controller as this is not an option from the storyboard.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths, usually, one should implement include both protocols in the interface declaration: `@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>`. Then, in Storyboard, just link datasource and delegate outlets to your view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method. I tried a quick sample project with a tableView in a view controller rather than in a UITableViewController and encountered the error you describe. When I manually generated the cell using

`[UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"testCell"];`

it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks too for your help. As above I have tried what you suggest and get the same error: -[UITableView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Any further thoughts?

Comment: I think Vova is right (again; excellent original answer that you should probably accept). If I were you, I would temporarily change tableView:numberOfRowsInSection to return a fixed number. That will split the problem in half: do you have a problem with setting the data source, or with teacherNames?

Comment: Incidentally, I notice that you also implement the numberOfSectionsInTableView: method but return 1. If you know the number of sections will always be 1, you can delete that code. The method is optional, and defaults to 1.